# Need help pulling just one value from a multi-dimensional associative array

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a pretty dumb question, but I'm a PHP novice. I'm storing the results of a query in one element of an associative array ($result["data"]). The data looks something like this:

```
id     f1     f2     f3
143    1      21     33
143    312    31     4433
143    22     312    412
```

The id field is guaranteed to store the same value for all elements of the array. I want to store that value (143 in the above sample table) in a variable. I've tried things along the lines of $result["data"]["id"][0], but nothing I try seems to work. I know there's probably a really simple way to do this. What is it?

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($result['data'])`

Comment: how are you selecting from the data base?

Comment: Please refer to the **Related** section at the bottom right of this page for a long LONG list of duplicates of this question.

Comment: It's probably `$result['data'][0]['id']`

Comment: Have you tired... $result["data"][1][0]

Comment: What code do you use for fetching results into the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$id = $result['data'][0]['id'];
```